# How to retain the values across connections in websocket server?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Below is the websocket server side code that uses "ws" plugin.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
   ,wsSend = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080}) //Client sends message on this port.
   ,wsReceive = new WebSocketServer({port: 8081}) //Response is sent on this port.
   ,clientMessage;

    wsSend.on('connection', ReceiveSocketConnection);//From client.

    //Callback function on connection with client.
    function ReceiveSocketConnection(webSocket) {
        webSocket.on('message', GetMessageFromClient);
    }

    //Handler to receive message from client.
    function GetMessageFromClient(messageFromClient) {
       clientMessage = messageFromClient; //Message from client saved into variable
    }

    wsReceive.on('connection', SendSocketConnection);//To client.

    function SendSocketConnection(webSocket) {
        webSocket.send(clientMessage);//Here clientMessage is undefined
    }
```

Below is the client side code.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
        , wsSend = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080') //send port
        , wsReceive = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081'); //receive port


        //Open connection on send port.  
        wsSend.on('open', function() {
            wsSend.send('Hi I am new to websockets');
        });

        //Open connection on receive port.  
        wsReceive.on('open', function() {
            //Do nothing
        });

        //Receive message from server via port 8081
        wsReceive.on('message', function(message) {
            console.log('received: %s', message);
        });
```

Separate ports for sending and receiving messages are there because it is a design decision.

I want to echo the message by receiving it on one port and sending it on another.

Problem : The message from the client is not saved into the local variable(i.e clientMessage).Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

this should work, however i recommend using http://socket.io/

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
   ,wsSend = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080}) //Client sends message on this port.
   ,wsReceive = new WebSocketServer({port: 8081}) //Response is sent on this port.

wsReceive.broadcast = function(data) {
  for(var i in this.clients)
  this.clients[i].send(data);
};

wsSend.on('connection', function(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message); 
    try {
      console.log('sending: %s', message);
      wsReceive.broadcast(message);
    } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have posted the client side code too..Wasn't sure how to fit your code.